# Issue with Jquery Sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slide

**HTML**

```
<div id="MyForm">
    <a> <img src="ImageMenu.png" /></a>

    <div id="form" style="width:250px">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%" style="color:White">
                    Name
                </td>
                <td width="3%">
                    :
                </td>
                <td width="27%">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="center">
                    <asp:Button Text="Send" runat="server" ID="btnSend" OnClick="btnSend_Click" OnClientClick="return Validate()"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
 $("#MyForm").click(
        function () { $("#form").slideToggle(400); }
    );
```

My Problem is that when ever I click on the textbox to enter data or clicking on button, the form is sliding up. Also, I have written JavaScript Validation function named "Validate()". When the Validation fails, the form is also sliding up.

Comment: `#MyForm` wraps the entire form, so your essentially clicking the `div` every time, therefore will slide every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
$("#MyForm>a").click(
        function () { $("#form").slideToggle(400); }
    );
```